# How to assign sequence number for a column with duplicated rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I want to assign sequence number to a column with duplicated rows, for example:

```
variable_1
   x
   x
   y
   y
   x
   x
   x
   z
   z
   z
```

How do I get the result like this:

```
variable_1   sequence
     x          1
     y          2
     x          3
     z          4
```

I tried using unique, but I would miss the sequence number for x showing up the second time.

Comment: `within.list(rle(df1$variable_1), lengths <- seq_along(lengths))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(sequence = rleid(variable_1)) %>%
  distinct()
df2
#   variable_1 sequence
# 1          x        1
# 2          y        2
# 3          x        3
# 4          z        4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
variable_1
                x
                x
                y
                y
                x
                x
                x
                z
                z
                z
                ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df = read.table(text = "
variable_1
x
x
y
y
x
x
x
z
z
z
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = if_else(variable_1 != lag(variable_1), 1, 0, missing = 1),  # flag row when variable changes
         sequence = cumsum(flag)) %>%                                       # create a group using the flags
  distinct(variable_1, sequence)                                            # get unique values

#   variable_1 sequence
# 1          x        1
# 2          y        2
# 3          x        3
# 4          z        4
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
v=(df$variable_1!=lag(df$variable_1))
v[is.na(v)]=T
df$sequence =cumsum(v)
df[!duplicated(df),]
variable_1 sequence
1          x        1
3          y        2
5          x        3
8          z        4
```

Comment: `shift` is not a base R function.

Comment: In that instance, you should check that it works in a fresh R session. The base R version of `lag` is meant to work with time series.